# Slow Response After Clicking Button in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, performance, event-handling, windows-mobile

I have created a windows form on a Windows Mobile 6.5 application. This screen has a username and password field and a login menu button. After clicking the button, it takes my click event for the login button 6 or 7 seconds to reach the first line of code (an alert). It takes that long to reach the breakpoint as well.

I've tried:

1. changing the menu button to a login button
2. using AddHandler in my formLoad event

...and have still not gotten a fast response. What else could be slowing this down?

Comment: It could be a lot of things (web.config, http request ...). Please give us some more contextual informations.

Comment: This delay only occurs on my login form. If I click a button on any other form, there is no delay.

Comment: And I'm not calling anything before my alert, so my alert should just pop right up.

Comment: Is the alert in client side or server?

Comment: Have you done any logic at all on the login page? like encryption or any security oriented? Can you say if the login page is wrapped on anything or waiting for any response? I'm asking those, because your problem is most likely due to the delay of another party to respond... Look into it and if you have more info post them, so we can go further.

Comment: There is some logic on this page, however, if I create a new button and don't put anything else inside of the event, I still get the delay. The page is not inheriting from anything. It does seem like the page is waiting for a response.

I looked into it some and it looks like the delay only occurs the first time any button is pressed on this page. The second time the button is pressed, it responds instantaneously. Is there some kind of delay with the event handler the first time any button is pressed in a vb.net program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This delay seemed to happen the first time any button was clicked on the application. The only way I could get this delay to not occur was to force a dummy button click of the login button on load of the application. The delay causes the application to load a little bit longer, but at least that delay won't occur when the user clicks the button.

Comment: I think I understand what is happening, on the fist load of modified pages, you have an ON REQUEST BUILD for any page that is impacted by those changes.  Try to run it, navigate through pages and load your login page a bit later (but do not quit debugging). I think this time even if you do not use the "fake" button, you will have your application to respond immediately. Have a nice day!